# How does PHP implements its all fit container `array`?

Tags: php, c, php-internals

If it were `c++`,this can be achieved by template,but as we know `PHP` is written in `c`,how's this kind of data struct implemented without template?

Comment: maybe its just me, but this question makes little sense.

Comment: php arrays can take any arbitrary content, a templated vector in c++ can only hold many objects of the same type (but you can create different vectors of course)

Answer (score 3):

It's a hash table. For the implementation details, see

- http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_hash.c?view=markup
- http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/zend_hash.h?view=markup

or in general

- http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/Zend/